# Android cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

I'm getting "cannot be resolved to a type" in my code. I'm looking for solution but all solutions are not working.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Vortex extends Activity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = Vortex.class.getSimpleName();
    private VortexView _vortexView; //there is the problem

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _vortexView = new VortexView(this);
        setContentView(_vortexView);
    }
}
```

The problem is with VortexView in this code. Eclipse tell me that VortexView cannot be resolved to a type.

Any solution?

Comment: Without seeing the code for VortexView, it's impossible to answer. Please can you post the code, at least the declaration, for VortexView?

Comment: Eclipse is telling you or the compiler is telling you? In Eclipse you need to add the directory that contains the source for this as a source directory in the project settings. If this class is in a jar file then you will need to add the jar.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have VortexView class in your project, if so, ctrl+shift+O will resolve the issue. Otherwise add class/jar to classpaht and do ctrl+shift+O (organize imports).

Answer (score 2):

VortexView is your custom view? If there exists VortexView.class

Comment: Thank You very much fof help. I added VortexView class in wrong place. OMG!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have made either of the following two mistakes.

1. You have not extended a view named VortexView at all
2. You have extended it correctly, but you haven't made it available to the current package

When you are doing such things, it is better to define custom views inside the same package. Or even though you are defining it somewhere else, make it avilable where it is used.

```
import yourPackage.VortexView;
```

Hope this helps.